# How would you detect if a user input is in a dictionary?

Tags: python

```
names_to_classgrades : {'Brad' : 75, 'Abigail' : 98, 'Carl' : 92}
choice = int(input("Press one if you want to update an existing students grade, press two if you want to add a new student and a new grade, press three to check the gradebook, and press four to exit. "))

def pressed_one():
  student_update = input("Which student's grade would you like to change? ")
  if student_update in names_to_classgrades.keys():
    denominator == 2
    new_grade = int(input("What is this student's new class grade? "))
    names_to_classgrades[student_update] = new_grade
    print(names_to_classgrades)

def pressed_two():
  new_student = input("What is the name of the student you want to add? ")
  new_student_grade = int(input("What is " + new_student + "'s grade in the class?"))

if choice == 1:
  pressed_one()
if choice == 2:
  pressed_two()
```

This is my code. The issue that I'm having is that there is a syntax error with the if statement on line six. Every time I run the pressed_one function, it says that the name 'names_to_classgrades is not defined. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not created the dict properly. You missed an `=`

```py
names_to_classgrades = {'Brad' : 75, 'Abigail' : 98, 'Carl' : 92}
```

Further, you haven't defined `denominator` and the line

```py
denominator == 2
```

serves no purpose.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! It is now fixed and it is running.

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept the answer if it solved the issue. :)

Comment: @Legen, BTW, your code is valid syntax because the dictionary after the colon in  `names_to_classgrades : {'Brad' : 75, 'Abigail' : 98, 'Carl' : 92}` is an [annotation](https://realpython.com/lessons/annotations/)

Comment: @DeepakGouda it says I have to wait four minutes and ForceBru I'm not sure what an annotation is but I put the equal sign and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
names_to_classgrades = {'Brad' : 75, 'Abigail' : 98, 'Carl' : 92}
choice = int(input("Press one if you want to update an existing students grade, press two if you want to add a new student and a new grade, press three to check the gradebook, and press four to exit. "))

def pressed_one():
  student_update = input("Which student's grade would you like to change? ")
  if student_update in names_to_classgrades:
    #denominator == 2
    new_grade = int(input("What is this student's new class grade? "))
    names_to_classgrades[student_update] = new_grade
    print(names_to_classgrades)

def pressed_two():
  new_student = input("What is the name of the student you want to add? ")
  new_student_grade = int(input("What is " + new_student + "'s grade in the class?"))

if choice == 1:
  pressed_one()
if choice == 2:
  pressed_two()
```

This would work,

There were few problems in the code,

1. Dictionary was not assigned properly

> names_to_classgrades : {'Brad' : 75, 'Abigail' : 98, 'Carl' : 92}

2. No use of

> #denominator == 2

3. "==" is used to compare 2 values and "=" is used for assignment